# Worklight-related error while using the Worklight iOS Native API

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting an error in Xcode when trying to connect to Worklight using the iOS native API:

```
[ERROR] Worklight: +[WLCookieManager persistentStoreCoordinator]:326::Unresolved error creating persistent store Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x1e59d0d0 {URL=/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/2C2E0482-7F42-4574-B998-A9FB5479F4B1/Library/Application%20Support/Cookies.sqlite, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Cookie = <3c2e440d 9fb3ea81 60146cf8 2bcb8ffe 10b2df20 0d907eea 018c6ade eeefb9c7>;
        UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "0F344BFF-833C-4009-9867-13973A5291F1";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=Can't find model for source store}, {
    URL = "file:///iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/2C2E0482-7F42-4574-B998-A9FB5479F4B1/Library/Application%20Support/Cookies.sqlite";
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            Cookie = <3c2e440d 9fb3ea81 60146cf8 2bcb8ffe 10b2df20 0d907eea 018c6ade eeefb9c7>;
            UserDictionaryEntry = <f0c9025b 602122f9 37a4e274 bdaacec1 b9a66f83 fca5c43b bed5e80a 6baee338>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;
        NSStoreUUID = "0F344BFF-833C-4009-9867-13973A5291F1";
        "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
    };
    reason = "Can't find model for source store";
}
```

This happens when I try to call this line:

```
[[WLClient sharedInstance] wlConnectWithDelegate:connectListener];
```

It was working fine and I was able to connect to my Worklight server without any issue, but now it keeps throwing this error. The only change I made was to try and show a dialog from the application. After reverting this change I still get the error.

Comment: Background on what it is that you're doing to begin with, will help in investigating the cause of the error.

Comment: It looks like it could be a timing issue. When you use the native API, you connect and then invoke. It is really strange, but what I am finding is that I start the app, then connect, it crashes. If I start the app, then invoke, it works fine and if I call connect after that it is ok. It makes no sense at all.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it the API is persisting a connection to the server.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when all of the files required aren't built into your app bundle.  In the build target for your application make sure that all the (non-source) files that are part of the worklight native SDK appear in the 'Copy Files' section.
Here is a [link to the docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_copying_native_api_files_for_ios.html)

Comment: Everything seems to be there. I had everything set up and working and have not changed anything that should affect these.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed something in your web app that the application is now trying to save a cookie? Or getting one passed to it. It looks like WL is trying to store a cookie and that's not going well. Can you isolate the part of the app where this is triggered? Does it compile. Take a look at how this code is probably being used:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/core-data_schema-versioning-and-lightweight-migrations/
http://46424.com/question/133999#.USJnGVprP4Y